# Reading file contents in Windows Metro-style Javascript App

Tags: javascript, html, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have been banging my head for hours, reading (over and over) ever tutorial I can find on MSDN and Windows Dev Center; nothing has worked.

I cannot seem to read data from a plain text file!

Yes, I have added file associactions, and Yes, I have added declarations to my project.

The code, from msdn:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            // TODO: Initialize the page here.


            Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync("AvailableBalance.sv").then(function (contents) {
                // Add code to process the text read from the file
                document.getElementById("AvailableBalanceText").innerText = contents;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And:

`<h1 id="AvailableBalanceText"></h1>`

Does not work. The app loads fine - but just doesn't read (or doesn't display data) from the file.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readTextAsync` [doesn't take a file name -- it takes an IStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701487.aspx).

You need to obtain a reference to the file some somewhere, rather than just opening it. If it's a user file  then you need to open it by using documentsLibrary:

```
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.getFileAsync("sample.dat").done(function (yourFileHandle) {
    // you now have a file handle.
});
```

Note that this is in the documents library. If you need to access a file in the package, or other location (you can't access arbitrary paths in Metro, just the libraries, local data for your app, and your package), you need to use one of the other APIs. I recommend taking a looking the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597) for file access.

Comment: H - I tried your sample code and that still did not work. I also downloaded the sample file and opened it - but when I hit F5 - it outputs the following error: `Error 1 Could not find SDK "Microsoft.WinJS.1.0, Version=1.0". C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets 1682 6 FileAccess
`

Comment: A) that implies you aren't using the RTM version of Win8 b) when you say it doesn't work, it silently failed? Did you place the sample.dat in your my documents folder? If you provide an error handler (pass function as second parameter to .done), is an error reported?

Comment: Hey @Dominic H - Yeah, I'm using the Consumer Preview version of Windows 8. But the C++, C# and VB versions work fine. I did indeed copy a file to My Documents :) and it does fail silently, and I've tried passing error parameter, but I still get nothing. The app just loads normally, and just doesn't display anything. (other than other, irrelevant content)

Comment: You have to upgrade. There were breaking changes -- the documentation & sample I linked you do are for the RTM version.

Comment: Sigh. Wait a sec, isn't RTM 'Release to manufacturing'? So... it's already out in shops? Haven't even seen it advertised over here yet

Comment: Its on msdn already. I think Release preview may still be available for free. General availability is Oct 26th